# Does a DC battery have a live terminal?

Tags: batteries, mains

On the mains, there is a live and neutral cable each. In a battery, there is a positive and negative terminal.

I know that touching the live wire from the mains is dangerous and fatal, but touching the neutral wire is fine.

In, say, a car battery, which of the terminals is the live one, if any?

Comment: In all modern cars, the negative post of the starting battery is connected to the engine, chassis, and virtually all other components. So the positive post would be considered "live" or "hot". When disconnecting a battery, you should do so on the negative post, so if your wrench touches any part of the car, it will not cause a short. Also, if you touch the positive post, especially if your skin is sweaty or bleeding, you can get a dangerous shock if you also touch the car's frame.

Comment: I get the point of your question. But neutral is not always safe to touch. Usually it is safe. But some faults could lead to neutral being unsafe. Also, sometimes electricians use the wrong color wire, so you may THINK it is neutral but it might not be. I recommend you treat neutral and live wires with equal respect.

Comment: @PStechPaul  A 12 volt car battery won't give you a dangerous shock, no matter what you touch

Comment: As I said, the conditions for a dangerous electrical shock from a 12V car battery depend on conductivity of the skin as well as the path the current might take in the body. Sweaty skin tightly grasping a metal tool can provide a resistance of 1k or less, which would be 12 mA - well above level of sensation, and enough to cause muscle contraction or startled reaction and injury. If skin is bleeding, even a couple mA through the heart can be dangerous. http://mrdischke.com/gr-10-technology-2/railroad-crossing/effects-of-voltage-on-the-human-body/

Comment: @PStechPaul it may theoretically be possible to get a shock, but as a practical matter, 12 V is generally considered safe by regulatory authorities, even for wet environments. The lowest voltage I have ever got a shock from was around 50 V. It was just a tingle.

Comment: When I was in elementary school I was experimenting with a 1.5 volt doorbell battery and an electromagnet. It sure surprised me when I got a nasty shock when I disconnected it. Lesson learned about inductance, and to use safe practices when dealing with any electric power source.

Comment: Also, if you are in salt water and the positive 12V cable from a trolling motor in an aluminum boat comes loose and lands in the water, the current can be enough to "freeze" your muscles and you could drown.

Comment: @PStechPaul I don't think so. The salt water will provide a more conductive path around you instead of through you. You are just hypothesizing worst case scenarios that have never actually been observed. In order to get a shock from 12 V you would need to do something dramatic like pierce your skin with the electrodes, or touch them to your tongue or something like that.

Comment: There is a party trick or challenge where a silver coin is placed on the bottom of a fish tank filled with salt water, and two electrodes from a 12V battery are put in the tank to create a DC current. The challenge is to pick up the coin, but the current blocks or overloads nerve signals to the muscles and you can't control your fingers. I have not tried this, and I haven't found a reference for it (or the boating accident), but it seems plausible.

Comment: It seems possible that a frayed wire on the positive cable could pierce the skin of one hand, while your other hand (especially if sweaty) holds onto the grounded metal frame of the vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends on what you mean by "live"

In a domestic electrical system, the term is used to mean something that carries a very *different* voltage with respect to the ground you are standing on, or the wall you are leaning against. That "live" voltage can be very negative with respect to ground, or very positive, as is the case with mains AC, which oscillates between being very positive (+320V in the UK, +170V in the US) and very negative (-320V or -170V) *with respect to ground*.

The term "ground" (or "earth") is a bit vague, and shouldn't be confused with neutral. In fact, "live" is with respect to neutral, in contrast to what I just said, but since *somewhere* (either at your home, or at the local sub-station) neutral and ground (literally the soil of planet Earth) are connected together, generally you can assume that neutral and ground have the same or very similar potentials.

Therefore, if you touch the neutral wire with your finger (which you should *never* do, because maybe your home's wiring is bad, or something else is wrong), you should feel nothing. That's because the potential difference between your finger (now at neutral potential) and the world around you (at ground potential) is very small, ideally zero. The voltage presented across your body, from finger to feet (for example), is very small.

Touching anything "live" with your finger, though, will have very different results. With your finger now at "live" potential, alternating between +320V and -320V with respect to your feet which have ground potential, there's a very large potential difference between your finger and your feet, and a large amount of current can flow between them. A situation that could easily kill you.

The connection we call live is considered to have a different potential from the one we call neutral, or the one we call ground (or earth), but everything's relative. If instead you decided that the live wire's potential shall be considered fixed, you would be correct in saying that it is the neutral potential that is bouncing up and down (between +320V and -320V) relative to live! The only truth you can say about live and neutral is that the *voltage between them* is rising and falling, and the polarity of that voltage is reversing 50 or 60 times per second.

So, given two wires that come into your home, carrying a *potential difference* between them of +320V one instant and -320V the next, which one is live, which one is neutral? What distinguishes one from the other? The answer is that one of them is connected to a giant spike driven into the ground. That's the one whose potential has been clamped to the same potential your home and body has. That's the one that shouldn't kill you, because touching it won't present a large potential difference across parts of your body. That's the one called "neutral". The other one is live, and will kill you if you let it.

Your question is "can a battery have a live terminal?", so I'll get to that now.

Given that "live" generally means the wire with potential that is different from ground, and sometimes could imply that that's the dangerous one, then we have to define dangerous, and ground.

If you insist that live means only "dangerous" then a 12V battery can't possibly have a live terminal. It can't hurt you simply by touching it. Sure with wet hands and a heart condition you might be able to do yourself some harm by bridging the negative and positive terminals with your body, but 12V is generally considered harmless. In this sense, the term "live" doesn't really apply.

However, all systems have some idea of "ground". Take a car for instance, whose metallic chassis is often connected to the battery's negative terminal. From the perspective of the electrical systems in the car, that would be considered a "ground". The wire that brings the other potential, +12V from the battery's positive terminal, could be considered "live".

Some older cars connected the battery's positive terminal to their chassis, and by calling *that* ground, any wire that brings the other different potential of -12V (*negative* twelve volts) with respect to ground, could be called "live" also. The importance is the difference in potential, not the polarity, so in a vehicle where battery positive is connected to the chassis "ground", "live" would be considered the negative terminal of the battery!

So, if your definition of "live" is "the one that isn't ground", then sure, a battery can have a live terminal, but you have to have labelled the other one  as "ground" first.

Answer (score 4):

No. The only reason line power has a neutral is because that neutral is connected to the Earth somewhere.

And in that case, the difference between the neutral and the earth/ground connection is that the neutral carries the return current from the live terminal during normal operation whereas the earth/ground connection does not.

Also, touching the neutral is not fine. Granted, it is safer than touching the live because it is connected to earth/ground *somewhere* (and chances that's the potential you are also at). However, since the neutral carries current, it can develop a resistive voltage drop across it away from the earth/ground potential. That resistive voltage drop can cause the neutral to be sufficiently different from earth/ground to be hazardous.

Comment: What does "return current" mean when it is alternating?

Comment: @Lastinclass It just means the current is flowing in the opposite direction of the live, whatever direction that might be. The current that comes out of the wall, must go back into the wall.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "The only reason line power has a neutral is because that neutral is connected to the Earth somewhere."?

Comment: @Lastinclass Without the earth connection the potential difference between the live and neutral would still be 120V/240V or whatever the line voltage normally is. The problem is that this voltage can now be anything relative to the earth. You are at earth potential. That's bad. The live could be at 1000V+120V and the neutral could be at 1000V relative to ground.

Answer (score 3):

Most cars (all modern cars) use the positive battery terminal as "live" and the negative terminal as "ground." So the negative is kind of like the neutral, and the positive is kind of like the live wire in an AC system.

But the 12 V car battery is generally considered to be too low of a voltage to cause a shock. You can still get big sparks if you accidentally short 12 V to ground. And the 12 V battery can supply a lot of current into a short circuit, so you can melt wires and things of that nature. But generally you do not have to worry about getting a shock from a 12 V battery.